# Building Transactional Memory C++ Code in g++

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, transactional-memory

The cppreference website has a [(work in progress) page describing transactional memory c++ code](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/transactional_memory). This is the first example on the page

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
int f()
{
    static int i = 0;
    synchronized { // begin synchronized block
        std::cout << i << " -> ";
        ++i;       // each call to f() obtains a unique value of i
        std::cout << i << '\n';
        return i; // end synchronized block
    }
}
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> v(10);
    for(auto& t: v)
        t = std::thread([]{ for(int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) f(); });
    for(auto& t: v)
        t.join();
}
```

Toward the bottom of that page, there is an indication that this builds on gcc (`// GCC assembly with the attribute:`).

I can't get this to build on g++ 5.3.1:

```
$ g++ --std=c++11 -fgnu-tm -lpthread trx.cpp 
trx.cpp: In function ‘int f()’:
trx.cpp:7:5: error: ‘synchronized’ was not declared in this scope
     synchronized { // begin synchronized block
     ^

$ g++ --help | grep transaction

$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1) 5.3.1 20160413
```

gcc documentation *does* have [a page on transactional memory](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/TransactionalMemory), but the primitives are different (e.g., the atomic block is `__transaction_atomic`). The page on cppreference.com conversely appears to be related to [N3919](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3919.pdf), and uses the primitives from there.

How can this code be built with g++?

Comment: at the bottom it says you need to use gcc 6.1?

Comment: @Nim, Ooh, crap - missed that. Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [transactional_memory](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/transactional_memory) link you mention first says:

> Compiler support
>
> This technical specification is supported by GCC as of version 6.1 (requires `-fgnu-tm` to enable).

So you need [GCC 6](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/) (and probably [also](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html) `-std=c++1z` in addition to `-fgnu-tm` ....)